# What does runuser: cannot set groups mean

Tags: centos, nagios

I am  installing  nagios3 on  centos.

After stopping the nagios server and then restarting I get the message

Starting nagios  runuser: cannot set groups:Operation not permitted.

what does this mean

Comment: run it as root and you should be all set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things off the top of my head.  Does the group that belongs to the user your switching to exist?  Does the `runuser` command have the setguid sticky bit set?  Check the output of `ls -l $(which runuser)`.  Alternately, it's possible you might have a partition mounted with the `nosuid` flag.  Check the output of `mount` for that.


--Christopher Karel

Comment: I didn't get it. I don't have the sticky bit. and i dont see a nosuid flag in the output of mount too.